# ixgbe driver: Limit the max number of cores

Tags: linux, drivers

I have a Linux workstation with 48 cores and runs ixgbe driver for
fiber interface. And I have to test a project name
[Netmap](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/) on it.

NetMap is a high performance network framework for high speed
interfaces, which has been ported to Linux recently. For some reasons,
I must try it on the machine.

So I compile it and follow the instructions to run the test problems,
but it doesn't work.

I check dmesg and it says:

```
[10399.085736] 794.159015 netmap_set_ringid [486] ringid o4o1 set to all 48 HW RINGS

[10399.085742] 794.282011 netmap_obj_malloc [220] netmap_if request size 816 too large
```

I asked the author of netmap for help. He told me that I have too many cores in the machine and it should work if I tell ixgbe use less cores (2 to 4 is ok).

I am not familiar to driver development and I don't know how to limit the ring numbers by passing arguments to ixgbe driver. So I check the spec from intel's website but found nothing about it. So I come here for more helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

a quick fix to let netmap work with large numbers of cores is
to apply this change to net/netmap/netmap_mem2.c

```
-#define NETMAP_IF_MAX_SIZE      256
+#define NETMAP_IF_MAX_SIZE      1024
```

cheers
luigi rizzo